# Bayesian networks problem

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, bayesian, bayesian-network

Attempting to understand Exercise 20 (pdf page 44) in [this book](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Barber/textbook/090310.pdf):

> The party animal problem corresponds to the network in g(3.14). The boss is angry and the worker has a headache - what is the probability  the worker has been to a party? All variables are binary and
>
> $p(U =tr|P =tr,D=tr)=0.999$, $p(U =tr|P =fa,D=tr)=0.9$, $p(U =tr|P =tr,D=fa)=0.9$, $p(U =tr|P =fa,D=fa)=0.01$.
>
> $\begin{matrix} & & D \\ & & \downarrow \\ P & \rightarrow & U \\ \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ (H) & & (A)\end{matrix} $

I'm unsure of how to solve this problem given only the above information, and help greatly appreciated. Can this even be solved with the information given in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up, you're referring to an old edition of the book, where this exercise is *incomplete*. Here's the [latest edition](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Barber/textbook/091117.pdf), where the same exercise specifies *all* necessary probabilities (p.57, ex. 3.1):

> - $p(U = tr|P = tr, D = tr) = 0.999$
> - $p(U = tr|P = fa, D = tr) = 0.9$
> - $p(U = tr|P = tr, D = fa) = 0.9$
> - $p(U = tr|P = fa, D = fa) = 0.01$
> - $p(H = tr|P = tr) = 0.9$
> - $p(H = tr|P = fa) = 0.2$
> - $p(A = tr|U = tr) = 0.95$
> - $p(A = tr|U = fa) = 0.5$
> - $p(P = tr) = 0.2$
> - $p(D = tr) = 0.4$

As you can see, the edges $P \rightarrow U$ and $D \rightarrow U$ aren't defined explicitly, so the **step one** is compute them using the Law of total probability (I use $!X$ notation to denote $X = false$):

$$p(U | P) = p(U | P, D)p(D) + p(U | P, !D)p(!D) = 0.999\cdot0.4 + 0.9\cdot0.6 = 0.9396$$

$$p(U | !P) = p(U | !P, D)p(D) + p(U | !P, !D)p(!D) = 0.9\cdot0.4 + 0.01\cdot0.6 = 0.366$$

and similarly

$$p(U | D) = 0.9198$$
$$p(U | !D) = 0.188$$

At this point, you can forget the first four given equations, because you have all probabilities of all edges in the network, and can compute any joint or conditional probability.

**Step two**: the end goal is to compute

$$p(P | H, A) = \frac{p(P, H, A)}{p(H, A)}$$

This is where things get a bit hairy, because $p(P, H, A)$ is a sum of *four* terms (marginilize over $D$ and $U$):

$$p(P, H, A) = p(P, H, A, D, U)p(D, U) + ... + p(P, H, A, !D, !U)p(!D, !U)$$

...and $p(H, A)$ is sum of *eight* terms (marginilizing over $D$, $U$ and $P$). I'll just show how to compute any of these terms and leave the rest to you as an arithmetic exercise.

The joint probability over Bayesian (sub-)network can be computed using Bayesian rule, e.g.

$$p(P, H, A, D, U) = p(H|P)p(A|U)p(U|P)p(U|D) = 0.9\cdot0.95\cdot0.9396\cdot0.9198 = 0.7389286884$$

$$p(D,U) = p(U|D)p(D) = 0.9198\cdot0.4 = 0.36792$$

$$p(!D,!U) = p(!U|!D)p(!D) = (1 - p(U|!D))p(!D) = (1 - 0.188)\cdot0.6 = 0.4872$$

And so on until you have $p(P, H, A)$ and $p(H, A)$, which will give you $p(P|H,A)$.

Comment: $p(U | P)$ and $p(U| D)$ calculations are not necessary. Actually, the question can be solved much simpler. Just get rid of the condition and write that as a a division, and notice that the numerator (sum of 4 terms) appears in half of the denominator. The answer is 0.609

Answer (score 3):

Using the values provided in the book and by Maxim:

$p(U=tr|P=tr,D=tr)=0.999$

$p(U=tr|P=fa,D=tr)=0.9$

$p(U=tr|P=tr,D=fa)=0.9$

$p(U=tr|P=fa,D=fa)=0.01$

$p(H=tr|P=tr)=0.9$

$p(H=tr|P=fa)=0.2$

$p(A=tr|U=tr)=0.95$

$p(A=tr|U=fa)=0.5$

$p(P=tr)=0.2$

$p(D=tr)=0.4$

As the possibility of having headache only depends on the possibility of the worker going to a party (not directed path from any other component), $P(H = T|P = T)$ and $P(H = T|P = F)$ do not depend on any other factor. Hence, the given condition's probability is the weighted sum of each of the cases:

Equation 1:

$P(H = T, A = T) = P(H = T|P = T) P(H = T, A = T, P = T) + P(H = T|P = F) P(H = T, A = T, P = F)$

Equation 2: Aim is to find:

$P(P = T| A = T, H = T) = (P(H = T|P = T) P(P = T, H = T, A = T))/ P(H = T, A = T)$

Finding $P(H = T, A = T, P = T)$ required in Equation 1:

$P(P = T, H = T , A = T) =$

$P(P=T) P(D=T) P(U=T|D=T,P=T) P(A=T|U=T)$
$+ P(P=T) P(D=T) P(U=F|D=T,P=T) P(A=T|U=F)$
$+ P(P=T) P(D=F) P(U=T|D=F,P=T) P(A=T|U=T)$
$+ P(P=T) P(D=F) P(U=F|D=F,P=T) P(A=T|U=F) $

$= (0.2)(0.4)(0.999)(0.95) + (0.2)(0.4)(0.0001)(0.5) + (0.2)(0.6)(0.9)(0.95) + (0.2)(0.6)(0.1)(0.5)$

$ = 0.075924 + 0.00004 + 0.1026 + 0.006 $
$ = 0.184564$

Finding $P(H = T, A = T, P = F)$ required in Equation 1:

$P(P = F, H = T , A = T) = $

$P(P=F) P(D=T) P(U=T|D=T,P=F) P(A=T|U=T)$
$+ P(P=F) P(D=T) P(U=F|D=T,P=F) P(A=T|U=F)$
$+ P(P=F) P(D=F) P(U=T|D=F,P=F) P(A=T|U=T)$
$+ P(P=F) P(D=F) P(U=F|D=F,P=F) P(A=T|U=F)$

= $(0.8)(0.4)(0.9)(0.95) + (0.8)(0.4)(0.1)(0.5) + (0.8)(0.6)(0.01)(0.95) + (0.8)(0.6)(0.99)(0.5)$

$= 0.2736 + 0.016 + 0.00456 + 0.2376$

$= 0.53176$

Substituting obtained values into Equation 1:

$P(H = T, A = T) = P(H = T|P = T) P(H = T, A = T, P = T) + P(H = T|P = F) P(H = T, A = T, P = F)$

$P(H = T, A = T) = P(H = T|P = T)(0.184564) +  P(H = T|P = F)(0.53176)$

$P(H = T, A = T) = (0.9)(0.184564) + (0.2)(0.53176)$

$P(H = T, A = T) = 0.2724596$

Reiterating Equation 2:

$P(P = T| A = T, H = T) = (P(H = T|P = T) P(P = T, H = T, A = T))/ P(H = T, A = T)$

$P(P = T| A = T, H = T) = P(H = T|P = T)(0.184564)/P(H = T, A = T)$

$P(P = T| A = T, H = T) = (0.9)(0.184564) / 0.2724596$

$P(P = T| A = T, H = T) = 0.6096595$